# Rewrite Rule. Drop everything after a string

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a quite a number of 404 urls where I would like to rewrite these rules when the string contains the word "where".

Any characters after and including the "where" are dropped.

So for example:
http://www.website.com.au/category/subcategory/where/colour/black

would become

http://www.website.com.au/category/subcategory/

I have the following rewrite, but I would like it the be more generic.

```
location /category/subcategory/where/colour/black {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com.au/category/subcategory/ redirect;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated
Brendan

Comment: /category/subcategory should be generic too?

Comment: Hi,

Yes, it should be generic also.

location /anything/anything/where/colour/black

so really if there is a /where/ in the url, chop off the characters after the where clause, keeping the existing start of the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location ~* ^/(.+)/where/ {
    rewrite ^(.+)/where/ $1 redirect;
}
```